# on calling API through a service RecyclerView glitches when i observe dataList with LiveData

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, rest

I have to display data in real time. So i have created a service and added a timer. I am hitting Rest API after every 1 min and storing data in room-Bb.

Problem: After every one minute when a service is called my adapter gets reset and my recyclerView blinks again and again after every one minute and i reach to top of the list even i have scrolled a list.

In my activity which is the base of my fragment i have called MySimpleService . In the service i have used a timer to call my API after every one minute to check if i got any new booking. And whenever my API is called my list gets updated and my Recyclerview Adapter get reset due to notifydatasetchanged() in setBookingData Method in my adapter. So my recyclerView Keep on Blinking After Every One Minute.

Here is my code

MySimpleService

```
 public class MySimpleService extends Service {
        private static final String TAG = "MyTag";
        private Timer mTimer;
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 10000; // 1 Minute
        private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 0;
        private MyDatabase appDatabase;
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            appDatabase = MyDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            Log.d(TAG, "MySimpleService onCreate: ");
            if (mTimer != null)
                mTimer = null;
            // Create new Timer
            mTimer = new Timer();
            // Required to Schedule DisplayToastTimerTask for repeated execution with an interval of `1 min`
            mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DisplayToastTimerTask(), TIMER_DELAY, TIMER_INTERVAL);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MySimpleService onStartCommand: ");
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }
    
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            Log.e(TAG, "My Service onDestroy: ");
            // Cancel timer
            mTimer.cancel();
        }
    
    
        private class DisplayToastTimerTask extends TimerTask {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(() -> {
                    if (Utils.getConnectivityStatus(getApplicationContext()) == 0) {
                        Utils.showOkAlert(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.info), "Please check your internet connection", false);
                    } else {
                        new Thread(() -> callApbookingList()).start();
                        new Thread(() -> callApiAssignList()).start();
                        new Thread(() -> callApiBookingActivitiesList()).start();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    
        private  void callApbookingList() {
            RetrofitApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitApiInterface.class);
            Call<BookingDataResponse> call = apiInterface.getAllData(new PostContData(PreferenceData.getLong(getApplicationContext(), "cont_id")));
            call.enqueue(new Callback<BookingDataResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<BookingDataResponse> call, Response<BookingDataResponse> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        BookingDataResponse body = response.body();
                        appDatabase.myDao().deleteBookingList();
                        if (body.getStatus() == 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + body.getMessage());
                                new Thread(() -> {
                                    try {
                                        appDatabase.myDao().insertBooking(body.getBookingList());
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                    }
                                }).start();
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<BookingDataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t);
                }
            });
        }
```

My Fragment

```
public class BookingAssignFragment extends Fragment {
    private BookingViewModel bookingViewModel;
    private BookingListAdepter bookingListAdepter;


    public BookingAssignFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking_assign, container, false);
        bookingListAdepter = new BookingListAdepter(getActivity());
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rev_booking_list);
        TextView errorMessasge = view.findViewById(R.id.error_message);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(bookingListAdepter);
        bookingViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(BookingViewModel.class);
        bookingViewModel.getBooking().observe(getActivity(), bookingLists -> {
            if (bookingLists.isEmpty()) {
                if (errorMessasge.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                    errorMessasge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                if (errorMessasge.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                    errorMessasge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              //  bookingListAdepter.setBookingData(bookingLists);
            }
            bookingListAdepter.setBookingData(bookingLists);
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

My Adapter

```
   public class BookingListAdepter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookingListAdepter.BookingViewHolder> {
    private List<BookingList> bookingLists;
    private  LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;

    public BookingListAdepter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext =context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BookingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View  view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_booking_list, parent, false);
        return new BookingViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookingViewHolder holder, int position) {
        BookingList li = bookingLists.get(position);
        if(li.getPlanType().equalsIgnoreCase("Both Way")){
            if (holder.numberOfDay.getVisibility()==View.GONE) {
                holder.numberOfDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.numberOfDay.setText(String.valueOf(li.getBookingDays()));
            }
        }else {
            if (holder.numberOfDay.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            holder.numberOfDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }
        if (li.getPlanType().equals(li.getTerrifType())){
            if (holder.palanTyupe.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            holder.palanTyupe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else { if (holder.palanTyupe.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
            holder.palanTyupe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
        holder.packageName.setText(li.getPlanType());
        holder.cabCategory.setText(li.getCabCategory());
        holder.dateTime.setText(li.getDatetime());
        holder.formLocation.setText(li.getFromLocation());
        holder.toLocation.setText(li.getToLocation());
        holder.amount.setText(String.valueOf(li.getTotalAmount()));
        holder.paidWalletAmount.setText(String.valueOf(li.getPaidWalletAmount()));
        holder.assignBooking.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (Utils.getConnectivityStatus(mContext) == 0) {
                Utils.showOkAlert(mContext,mContext.getString(R.string.info), "Please check your internet connection", false);
            }else {
                BookingAssignDialogFragment updateDriver = BookingAssignDialogFragment.newInstance(li.getBookingId(), PreferenceData.getLong(mContext,"cont_id"),0,"");
                updateDriver.show((Activity) mContext);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (bookingLists!=null)
            return bookingLists.size();
        else return 0;
    }
    public void setBookingData(List<BookingList> bookingData) {
        bookingLists = bookingData;
        Log.d("UpdatedBooking", String.valueOf(bookingLists.size()));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    class BookingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     TextView packageName,palanTyupe,cabCategory,amount,formLocation,toLocation,dateTime,numberOfDay,paidWalletAmount;
     ImageView assignBooking,acceptBooking;
        public BookingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            packageName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.package_name);
            palanTyupe = itemView.findViewById(R.id.plan_type);
            cabCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cab_category);
            amount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            formLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.from_location);
            toLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.to_location);
            dateTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_and_time);
            numberOfDay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.no_of_day);
            assignBooking = itemView.findViewById(R.id.assign_booking);
            paidWalletAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.paid_wallet_amount);
            acceptBooking =itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept_booking);
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel

```
public class BookingActivitiesListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {


    private BookingActivitiesListRepository bookingActivitiesListRepository;
    private LiveData<List<BookingActivitiesList>> mLiveData;

    public BookingActivitiesListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        bookingActivitiesListRepository = new BookingActivitiesListRepository(application);
        mLiveData = bookingActivitiesListRepository.getBookingActivitiesList();
    }

    public LiveData<List<BookingActivitiesList>> getBookingActivitiesList()
    {
        return mLiveData;
    }
}
```

My Repository

```
public class BookingRepository {
   private MyDao myDao;
   private LiveData<List<BookingList>> mBookingList;
   BookingRepository(Application application){
       MyDatabase db = MyDatabase.getInstance(application);
       myDao = db.myDao();
       mBookingList = myDao.getBookingList();
   }

   LiveData<List<BookingList>> getBooking(){return mBookingList;}
```

My item_view_booking_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@style/ItemViewStyle"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".85">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_form_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/from_location"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_to_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/to_location"/>


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_car"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:id="@+id/cab_category"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_work_black_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/package_name"/>



            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="2560"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_rupee_indian"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:id="@+id/amount"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/wallet"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/paid_wallet_amount"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/date_and_time"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_date_range_black_24dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/no_of_day"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="plan type"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_work_black_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/plan_type"/>



        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/assign_booking"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/check_black"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/accept_booking"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"/>



    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My fragment_booking_assign xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.booking.assigned.UnassignedBooking.BookingAssignFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rev_booking_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp20"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/dp15"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/data_not_available"
        android:id="@+id/error_message"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_26dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After trying the code locally, I could not reproduce your issues, the only thing I had different is that I had the data mocked and did not use the service. So I went through your service class again, and I think I found the issue. In your service class, upon successfully requested new data, you do:

```
appDatabase.myDao().deleteBookingList();
```

As your `mBookingList`  liveData is updated by `myDao` (as you declared in your repository), this will cause `mBookingList` to update with empty list, hence the recyclerView resets to empty for a quick moment == blinking. Right after, you populate your DAO with new data, i.e. udpating your `mBookingList` with new data, causing populating of currently empty recyclerView with new data == seemingly scrolling to top (but actually what happened is that is just went from empty to full data).

So, to solve your issue, come up with implementation that updates your DB instead of clearing it and repopulating, OR avoid setting data for your recyclerView if the incoming dataset is empty.

Comment: Thank You Sir. I understood. I was not handling my list for a fraction of second when list was empty.